# ServiceStack OrmLite, A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I am trying ServiceStack OrmLite, but right now I am stumped with this exception: `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.`

There is no stacktrace either.

This is my OrmLite code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
            string DbConnection = "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=9530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSID)));uid=myusername;pwd=mypassword";

            var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(DbConnection, false, OracleDialect.Provider);

            using (var db = dbFactory.Open()) {
                var res = db.Select<Einduk>().Take(10);
                foreach (var einduk in res) {
                    Console.WriteLine(einduk.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my model class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Einduk
    {           
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Akaun { get; set; }
        public string Jenis { get; set; }
        public string Bakaun { get; set; }
        public string Oldac { get; set; }
        public string Plgid { get; set; }
        public string Pnama { get; set; }
        public string Almat { get; set; }
        public string Kslah { get; set; }
        public DateTime Trikh { get; set; }
        public decimal Amaun { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("Jenis: {0}, Akaun: {1}, Bakaun: {2}, Oldac: {3}, Plgid: {4}, Pnama: {5}, Almat: {6}, Kslah: {7}, Trikh: {8}, Amaun: {9}", Jenis, Akaun, Bakaun, Oldac, Plgid, Pnama, Almat, Kslah, Trikh, Amaun);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my table, note that **the table does not have a primary key**. But in my model I set `Akaun` as the primary key as I know it is unique. **Will this cause the problem?**

```
CREATE TABLE "EINDUK" 
(   
    "JENIS" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "AKAUN" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "BAKAUN" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "OLDAC" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "PLGID" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "PNAMA" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ALMAT" VARCHAR2(282 BYTE), 
    "KSLAH" VARCHAR2(508 BYTE), 
    "TRIKH" DATE, 
    "AMAUN" NUMBER
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in my model class I didn't set my properties as nullable, like so..

```
public DateTime? Trikh { get; set; }
public decimal? Amaun { get; set; }
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and posted to their github page
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/issues/267